# Rails routes custom nesting syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to map the following legacy url:

> /:user_id/comments

comments is a resource, so in an idea world I would use something like:

```
resources :users, :prefix => nil do
  resources :comments
end
```

Here I'm using prefix => nil but what I really want is to map just the user id. So instead of /users/:user_id/comments/ I have /:user_id/comments/.

Note that I'm not interested in declaring a users resource, so if there's something like a namespace that I can use instead all the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using was:

```
scope ':user_id' do
  resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a match statement to strip out the users folder:

`match '/:user_id/:comments' => '/users/:user_id/:comments'`

Comment: comments should still be a resource though, so I should also match /:user_id/comments/new, etc. I was wondering if there was a better way, otherwise I'll just use plain old match.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to scope the comments which should enable all of the RESTful paths.